# Which one is better on performane between lombok builder and lombok no//allargsconstructor annotation

Tags: java, lombok

Which one is better in peformance comparing between lombok builder and lombok no//allargsconstructor annotation when creating objects ?

```
Amount.builder().categoryCode("A").coveredAmount(new 
BigDecimal(100)).build();
```

or

```
Amount cva1 = new Amount();
cva1.setCoveredAmount(new BigDecimal(100));
cva1.setCategoryCode("A");
```

or

```
Amount cva1 = new Amount(new Bigdecimal(100), "A");
```

Comment: It’s doubtful object creation has any measurable impact on your app. Do you have a concrete problem with performance?

Comment: thank you for your reply, i want knew how to choose the best maner to create object

Comment: the best way is the most readable way. I would be much more worried about someone else reading the code and understanding it than runtime performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok is a compile-time-only tool and so has nothing to do with runtime performance.

It is an annotation processor that run during the java compilation `javac`.

Here you only want to compare creational patterns but it not something "link" to Lombok.

By the way it is opinion-based

Comment: Thank you, so the three ways I mentioned above to create an object are the same.
just another question, and in terms of execution time, they are all of the same order

Comment: Interesting question but should ask in another topic ;-)

Comment: i creared it her https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410500/faster-way-to-create-object-lombok-builder-vs-manually-declaration