# faster way to create object lombok builder vs manually declaration

Tags: java, lombok

Between these 3 way to create an object, which one is the faster in time of execution ?

```
Amount.builder().categoryCode("A").coveredAmount(new 
BigDecimal(100)).build();
```

or

```
Amount cva1 = new Amount();
cva1.setCoveredAmount(new BigDecimal(100));
cva1.setCategoryCode("A");
```

or

```
Amount cva1 = new Amount(new Bigdecimal(100), "A");
```

And the number of fields can be made difference ?

Comment: You should not start optimizing at this level unless you know that you have a performance problem at this very point. Choose the way that is the most comprehensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beyond the performance comparison (peanuts btw...) you should not use a object-creation strategy based on his execution time but merely on your real need , requirements and best practices.

1. `Fluent Builder pattern`

   - Better for readability
   - Optional attributes
   - Construction in multiple step

`Remark` : don't use this pattern to hide the fact that your class defines too many fields... use pattern like `extract class` instead of going through a builder construction.

2. `Javabean style`. This type of construction is (IMO) a bad practice because the time between the no-arg construction and calls to setters to initialize it,  the object stills in an inconsistent state.
3. `Primary constructor`. You prefer this way when all fields are `required`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets evaluate how many stack frames each syntax has (just a rough diagram, excuse my brevity):

```
1) builder() ->returns -> categoryCode() -> return this -> coveredAmount() -> return this
-> new BigDecimal() -> return BigDecimal -> return this -> finally build() -> returns Amount
```

So total 6 function calls.

```
2) ctr call -> return Amount -> setter -> bigdecimal -> return bigdecimal -> return setter -> (same again as last step)
```

So total 5 calls

```
For 3) only 2 function calls
```

By above analysis 3rd syntax wins but your compiler might optimize in such manner that all three would have similar execution time.

Comment: 287/5000
Thank you for your reply,
When you said that the compiler can optimize in all three cases,
so the compiler will optimize differently in the three cases? or is it the same optimization process?
if it's different, do you have an article link that can explain that?

Comment: you can read more about jdk code optimizations here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/underst_jit.html
but in case of lombok, i don't have any reference, jit might not be able to optimize that.